What interaction among wasps is this?
I found the following collection of, I think, wasps on a sidewalk in Fort Worth, TX in mid-December.  It looks to me like the aftermath of some battle, and it's not surprising to me that wasps had some sort of battle, but I can't understand what would have made them die in this frozen tableau.  (I mean frozen in the sense of "not moving," not cold; the temperature was probably high teens or low twenties Celsius.)  What might have happened here?



Most likely that they envenomated (stung) each other at roughly the same time.
You have two species of wasp here, possibly a common wasp (Vespula vulgaris), the German wasp (Vespula germanica) or one of the many USA-based yellowjackets (Vespula or Dolichovesupula species) as the smaller, yellow one, and a larger hornet species, possibly the European Hornet (Vespa crabro). Because they are different species, they are competing for resources, so they might well attack each-other.

Good answer. It looked like a duel to me as well. I wonder which wasp won? They both look scary to me.

@anongoodnurse If they're both dead, seems like a pyrrhic draw to me.
